# Choose which form to fill with same input name with cURL

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I have this HTML/PHP code with two forms : one to log in and one to sign in.
I would like to fill them with php cURL. This is my code so far :

My form.php file code is below

```
<html>  
<head>  
</head> 
<body>
    <form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <form id="register" action="register.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>     
</body> 
</html>
```

and

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init("form.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
'name' => 'test',
'email' => 'test'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    
?>
```

My question is : how can I select which form I want to fill, since they have the  same input name ?

I know I could just change the names of the input, but I'm interested in the answer there might be.

Thank you (PS: I'm french so my english might not be perfect) :)

Comment: you can add one more element in data called selectedform. When you go form.php at that time you just need to read it.

Comment: Should i add at the end of $data 'selectedForm'=>'login' ?

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Comment: Well it doesnt work until there, im going to continue to try

Comment: Im a bit confused right now : Ive created a php file a.php and the login form has now action="a.php". a.php is just `<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>`. I thought the cURL script would fill the form and submit it, which would redirect to a.php, but it doesn't. Have I missed something ?

Comment: Or is it just useful to call POST/PUT method on web apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cUrl is just going to be useful for making `http`/`https` calls.

What you need is a headless browser, try [phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/), i use that in my Node Projects, they also have a PHP version: http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/.

You send javascript calls, to PhantomJS, any data that your javascript function returns, is returned to you in to access it - in your case php.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search, I found out what I was looking for. I misunderstood the purpose of cURL. I thought it would send the form like a browser user would do, but it just sends POST/PUT request to a web page.
Indeed PhantomJS could have worked, but I prefer the Python way.
I'm going to try mechanize with Python, which I'm familiar with as well. 
Thank you for your answers :)